# Drive folder not being created

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

So i am trying to create a folder on google drive using python. I followed the documentation and everything and also used 0Auth2 authentication. For reference this is the code i am trying to debug

```
import os
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'assets/key/key.json'

def Authenticate():
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    print('Authentication Successful')
    return creds

def CreateFolder():
    creds = Authenticate();
    
    try:
        service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds);
    
        folder_metadata = {
            "name" : "AutoUpload",
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
        }
        folder = service.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields="id").execute()
        print(f'Folder created successfully! Folder ID: "{folder.get("id")}".')
        return folder.get("id")
    
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f'An error occured: {error}')
        return None
CreateFolder();
```

Duringe the debugging i get the expected results like the authentication being successfull and even getting back the folder id. But upon checking my drive, the folder is no where to be found. Even if i search for the folder directly on my drive it doesnt seem to be there. Can i get some help on what could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Your not seeing the file in your personal drive account because that's not where your uploading it to.

The metadata you are setting

```
folder_metadata = {
        "name" : "AutoUpload",
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    }
```

Shows that you are creating a folder and giving it a mime type of folder.  You are not setting a directory so there for it will go in to the root directory of the currently authenticated user.

As you are using a service account

```
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

The file will be uploaded to the service accounts google drive account.

You can see this by doing a files.list

```
folder = service.files().list().execute()
```

If you want to upload the file to your personal drive account you need to share a folder with the service account and then set parents in the metadata to be that of the folder your uploading to on your account.

Comment: I see what you mean. So if i want to create the folder in my main drive account and then upload the files there. What would be the recommended way of doing it

Comment: open the key file. get the service account email address its the one with a @ in it. share the directory on your personal drive account with the service account like you would any other user.   Then add parents to the metadata as i said.